# Excel 2007 "Wrap Text" button won't "de-wrap" certain cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document where after clicking on a cell that is apparently wrapping text, I can't simply click the Home Ribbon's "Wrap Text" button to stop wrapping.  Repeatedly clicking the "Wrap Text" button (or going to cell formatting checkbox) doesn't stop the cell from wrapping.  (I can clear the "wrap text" checkbox in formatting, but the ribbon button remains selected and the text remains wrapped)

I can type data into the cell so it doesn't appear to be protected, but this is a document that was generated with Apache NPOI, so some strange settings may be in effect.

Other "fresh/unused" cells in the document work just fine with the same text as the problem cells copied into them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FYI, I've had this same problem recently, when manipulating cells that had previously been merged.  It seems the wrap text button doesn't work (won't toggle off) if the horizontal or vertical alignment of the text inside is set to justify (no idea why it became justified in the first place though).

Re-setting the alignment to left/centre allowed me to un-wrap the text again.

Comment: I added justify property to a merged cell and i could un-merge it...

Comment: This justify is definitely onto something.  Merge and Center, then right click->formatting->Alignment->Justify definitely messes things up.  Justify seems to "lock" the wrap text option.  This must be the setting I had turned on without realizing it in NPOI.

Answer (score 2):

Excel supports line returns within a cell. Line returns are sometimes created from copied text.

One way to check for this is expand the height of the formula bar or the width of the column. Look if text is forced to a new line.

To add a manual line return click in the formula bar then Alt+return. 
To find the line return chr search for CHAR(10)

Another option is check for space characters. Sometimes externally generated content add spaces. If this is your situation a clear pattern will likely emerge when this occurs.

Comment: I'm assuming since copying the content to another cell makes makes things work correctly that it has nothing to do with cell content.  Note: I'm not sure how spaces would be any kind of problem here...

Comment: @ebyrob  Excel sometimes treats content differently. The imported data may be treated differently than the content copied from within XL. As for spaces, imported content sometimes brings lots of space chrs. Try a search for "  " double spaces ensuring Options > Look In = Values is selected. The Trim() function resolves errant spaces nicely.

Comment: Just to be clear, you've seen extra spaces cause a toggle button to not toggle in Excel?

Comment: I've misunderstood. I've seen extra spacing from data imports. This spacing results in seemingly odd XL appearance.

Comment: This is a problem where a button (setting) in Excel actually breaks and quits working properly due to <something unknown> in the excel file itself.  For these cells, even if I change the content, I cannot toggle the "Word Wrap" button any more.  It is as if it is "stuck on".  How it looks onscreen isn't relevant if I can't use the interface itself.  Note: We just upgraded to NPOI 2.1 and the problem went away on its own.  So now this is just a curiosity for me.

Answer (score 1):

I went to Alignment and changed the text alignment from Justify to General and it works after that.
For some reason it does not work in Justify mode.

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded to NPOI 2.1 and the problem went away.  So, now this is downgraded to a curiosity for me on what could cause it.

I'll mark this as answer at some point, but if someone has a better one feel free to post it, I will switch the check to the best answer I see.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the affected cells had no vertical alignment set. When I selected them and chose a vertical alignment setting the Wrap Text selection disappeared and they now seem to be behaving normally.

Answer (score 0):

All attempts at changing vertical alignment (Wrap Text included) were not working via ribbons or "Format Cells" dialog box / Alignment tab.  I was able to get it working again by closing all open Excel documents and reopening.

Answer (score 0):

I had copied information from one spreadsheet to another & forgot that some of my cells had the text running vertically. The numbers I was typing in the new spreadsheet were running vertically, and I thought it was a wrapping issue. You might check that.

Answer (score -1):

you can try my tips as follows: choose a number of cells including the "wrap text" cells, click "merge & center" button twice to merge and split those cells. Now the trouble cells are no longer "wrap text".
Hope this helpful :)

Comment: This is incorrect. I tried it. It did not work